# import multiple Excel files to pandas and export to multiple Stata files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, stata

1. My raw Excel files are:

`[excel_1.xlsx,excel_2.xlsx,...,excel_12.xlsx]`.

At first I want to import them into dataframes and then append them into a big dataframe, then `df.to_dta`, but python shows error and said:

`MemoryError`

I guess the problem is that the appended dataframe is too big.

2. So I thought I could transform each Excel file to each Stata file, which is:

`[excel_1.xlsx,excel_2.xlsx,...,excel_12.xlsx]`

to

`[excel_1.dta,excel_2.dta,...,excel_12.dta]`

and append them in Stata, but I don't know how to do that.

3. My original code was

```
import pandas as pd
IO = 'excel_1.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(io=IO, skiprows = [1,2] ,
                           dtype={"Opnprc": "str","Hiprc": "str","Loprc": "str","Clsprc": "str","Dnshrtrd": "str","Dnvaltrd": "str","Dsmvosd": "str",
                                  "Dsmvtll": "str","Dretwd": "str","Dretnd": "str","Adjprcwd": "str","Adjprcnd": "str","Markettype": "str",
                                  "Trdsta": "str"})

df.to_stata('excel1.dta')
```

I guess a `for` loop should work, but I don't know how to do that.

(the append code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


cwd = os.path.abspath('D:\\onedrive\\test2') 
files = os.listdir(cwd) 
print(files) 
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file, skiprows = [1,2] ,
                           dtype={"Opnprc": "str","Hiprc": "str","Loprc": "str","Clsprc": "str","Dnshrtrd": "str","Dnvaltrd": "str","Dsmvosd": "str",
                                  "Dsmvtll": "str","Dretwd": "str","Dretnd": "str","Adjprcwd": "str","Adjprcnd": "str","Markettype": "str",
                                  "Trdsta": "str"}), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 

df.to_stata('test.dta')
```

Comment: Have you tried Stata `import excel 'excel_1.xlsx'`, and then `append` ...?

Comment: show us your original code...

Comment: To append in Stata, use the `append` command.

Comment: I have tried append, but a **MemoryError** will be shown.  I will add the append code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to transform each Excel file to a Stata file using a `for` loop in python3.

```
import pandas as pd
IO = 'excel_{}.xlsx'
num_files = 12

for i in range(1, num_files + 1):
    df = pd.read_excel(
            io=IO.format(i), 
            skiprows = [1,2] ,
            dtype={"Opnprc": "str","Hiprc": "str","Loprc": "str","Clsprc": "str","Dnshrtrd": "str","Dnvaltrd": "str","Dsmvosd": "str",
                   "Dsmvtll": "str","Dretwd": "str","Dretnd": "str","Adjprcwd": "str","Adjprcnd": "str","Markettype": "str",
                   "Trdsta": "str"})
    df.to_stata('excel_{}.dta'.format(i))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!
But here is another problem , after using `df.to_stata('excel_{}.dta'.format(i))`
it says: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: I have found it is because one of my columns contain Chinese characters, but I dont know how to deal with that.